# Google map is not working outside the application

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, intel-xdk

My code for google map is working inside Intel XDK.but not working when I run on live app.how to recover this problem.

**index.html**

```
 <div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
   <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
   <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
 </div>
```

**app.js**

```
  $scope.launchGoogleMaps=function(){
     var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?ll="+$scope.temple.latitude+","+$scope.temple.longitude;
     intel.xdk.device.launchExternal(url);
 }
```

Comment: the code above is correct.but notr working in live application only.please give me a solution to fix

Comment: Please do not duplicate your own questions.